# How to align a text below a picture at the center of the div horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am making my pageresponsive for the screen size (max-width: 991px) to (min-width: 768px). Here i have a picture and some text below it i want it be aligned horizontally at the center:-

```
 <div class="col-lg-2 pictures_titles" >
                 <img class="team_img" src="../assets/img/Website-Png/About-Us-01-3.png">
                 <br><br>
                 <div class="name_titles">
                     <span id="namess" style="color:white;"><p> JAMES WILLIAMS </p></span>
                 <br>
                <span id="storys1" style="color:white;">
                     <p> An experienced strategist and entrepreneur, he is the Founder and Managing Director
                 of gorb.</p> </span>
                 </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text-align: center` will center text and inline elements

*Note, it is not allowed with `p` elements inside `span`, so I changed `span` to `div`*

```css
.pictures_titles {
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-2 pictures_titles">
  <img class="team_img" src="http://placehold.it/300x150">
  <br><br>
  <div class="name_titles">
    <div id="namess" style="color:white;">
      <p> JAMES WILLIAMS </p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="storys1" style="color:white;">
      <p> An experienced strategist and entrepreneur, he is the Founder and Managing Director of gorb.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want the text to be within the boundaries of the image, you could do like this, using `display: table-caption`

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}
.pictures_titles {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.name_titles {
  display: table-caption;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-2 pictures_titles">
  <div class="name_titles">
    <img class="team_img" src="http://placehold.it/300x150">
    <br><br>
    <div id="namess" style="color:white;">
      <p> JAMES WILLIAMS </p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="storys1" style="color:white;">
      <p> An experienced strategist and entrepreneur, he is the Founder and Managing Director of gorb.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For the screen sizw 768px it works but for 991px the text is shifted towards left a bit.

Comment: @UtkarshGautam Then you need to post those rules, as one does something the other does not

Comment: I gave width: 100% to .name_titles class and then it works perfectly.

Comment: @UtkarshGautam Very good. I also see you haven't accepted any answer given to questions. You are suppose to do that, so future user can benefit from knowing which answer you chose as the best, as you can with others, so please go through them accept an answer (if any) that best solved each

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could easily do that with CSS of course.

```
.name_titles {
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make image at center and text below it also aligned to center then use-

```
 <div class="col-lg-2 pictures_titles" style="text-align:center;">
             <img class="team_img" src="../assets/img/Website-Png/About-Us-01-3.png">
             <br><br>
             <div class="name_titles">
                 <span id="namess" style="color:white;"><p> JAMES WILLIAMS </p></span>
             <br>
            <div id="storys1" style="color:white;">
                 <p> An experienced strategist and entrepreneur, he is the Founder and Managing Director
             of gorb.</p> </div>
             </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I would avoid using inline CSS as much as possible. Instead tell the `pictures_titles` class to center the text.

Comment: you can create class for text-align:center; and can use that class instead of inline css.
Advantage would be you can use it in other places also.

Comment: Exactly ;) Since he's using col-lg-2 I assume he's using Bootstrap which already has this class. But if you have multiple picture titles then it would be better to set it on the class